# Mixed API Blueprint / MSON property

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, mson

I'm trying to create a data structure object. There are two possible values to one of its properties but they are of mixed type. Some of the time, it may be a number, but some of the time it may be an array of strings.

```
{"collectorNo": 285}
{"collectorNo": ["60a", "60b"]}
```

I think some sort of enum[string array[string]] might be needed but I can't seem to make it work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0):

what about using One Of type? Docs on https://apiblueprint.org/documentation/mson/specification.html#52-one-of-type, example below.

`- One Of
  - collectorNo: ["60a", "60b"] (array[string])
  - collectorNo: 285 (number)`